# Don't be too literal, take some numbers

Tags: riddle

> You can find me once in one,
> You can find me once in four,
> You cannot find me in ten,
> You cannot find me in five hundred.
>
> You think I am too easy to spot,
> That's because you did not find me.

Who am I?

Comment: I could use some help for that because I don't see a way to reword it without giving up the answer.

Comment: In fairness, the riddle hints there is an obvious answer that should be avoid.

Comment: @JLee with your suggestion, you know that **O** is not the answer, so it invalidate the last hint. At first I wanted to have only the 4 first lines but it was too broad since **O** will also match.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I guess the title and the last 2 lines are sufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> The letter I

You can find me once in one,

> One is I in Roman numerals.

You can find me once in four,

> Four is IV in Roman numerals.

You cannot find me in ten,

> Ten is X in Roman numerals.

You cannot find me in five hundred.

> 500 is D in Roman numerals.

You think I am too easy to spot, That's because you did not find me.

> The obvious answer is O (since you can find it in one, four, but not in ten or five hundred).

Comment: Well, nicely done! But I think this means the riddle is too broad. O fits just as well (and that's not just sour grapes :-p )

Comment: :) beaten by I minute :)

Comment: That was too easy

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is

> the letter O.

*You can find me once in one,

You can find me once in four,

You cannot find me in ten,

You cannot find me in five hundred.*

> The letter O appears once in each of "**o**ne" and "f**o**ur", but not at all in "ten" and "five hundred".

*You think I am too easy to spot,*

> O appears twice in "too", once in "spot", and looks like a spot itself (circular?)

*That's because you did not find me.*

> Hmph. See pacoverflow's answer for the intended (probably) solution.

Comment: That's not the answer. You fell for the red herring :)